# How can I run rosserial without errors?

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm new to ROS and I was trying to learn how to send a message from ROS to Arduino and the other way using rosserial. I am using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04.4 .

Until now I could include ros_lib into the Arduino IDE as it says in the following link http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup , so I tried to do the next tutorials, first one is the example step by step for publisher (with HelloWorld program) as http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World and the second one is the example for subscriber (with blinking of led program) as this link http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink.

First, I compile the code in the Arduino IDE  and it does not show any error and then I upload it. Also, I checked the port and the baud of Arduino.

So next, I am giving the following commands in the terminal:

1. Roscore
2. `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=9600`

And when I try to run that node I get the following error in both programs (so that's why I think I have the error in the node):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sofia_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 39, in <module>
    from rosserial_python import SerialClient, RosSerialServer
File "/home/sofia_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosserial_python/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SerialClient'
```

Since I'm new and I'm following the tutorials I do not know where is my error. I tried to look if there is something similar to this but I couldn't find anything resolved.

Thank you in advanced!! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330615/how-can-i-run-rosserial-without-errors?/) by [Naussicca](https://answers.ros.org/users/44795/naussicca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there is a problem with your rosserial_python installation. You have a setup mixed up between python 2 and 3. I suspect you installed rosserial_python with pip3. Uninstall it there and install it with `sudo apt install ros-YOURDISTRO-rosserial-python`.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-14**:
But also welcome to ROS. ;-) Please stay - we have cookies.

**Comment by [Naussicca](https://answers.ros.org/users/44795/naussicca/) on 2019-08-14**:
Hii! I love cookies hahaha :D
I did what you say and it works perfectly, so thank you so much!!
Greetings and hope you are having a good day!
Sofi

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-08-15**:
Good to hear. Can you please accept my answer (click the little tick)